# Get Facebook or Google profile information with Firebase API

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, sdk, firebase-authentication

I want to build an app to connect with people one of social networks sites like Facebook, Twitter. I want to know is it possible to get profile information with Firebase API or need to user their own SDKs to get those information. If yes I which will the best practice using Firebase or their own SDKs ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. it is possible. Read the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) here.

[Sample app](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/) also linked for github

If you are highly dependant on firebase for other things like notifications, database, etc. Its preferrable to use that, just my personal opinion.

Comment: Yes I want to build app to send notifications and etc. I will use most of firebase tools but I read documentation didn't find anything related to get facebook full profile including likes, friend list and etc.